# how could I link my HTML project to laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to create a webpage using laravel but there's not a lot of info online on how to actually set up everything together. I already downloaded ui:auth and there's already the login option in the laravel welcome page, my question is how do I link this to my HTML page? I already tried looking up for a file where the login info might be but whenever I link it in my HTML proyect it simply links to the raw file. So I must be doing something wrong. any help at all?

Comment: What do you mean by link your html project to laravel? Are you trying to port your html project into a laravel project?

Comment: @BenGooding yes Im trying to link up my laravel project with my HTML project if that makes sense. I want to link to the "login" option (brought by ui:auth) from the laravel welcome page to my html project, if that makes sense. please ask if im not being too clear

Comment: Yeah that makes sense I think, I've added a more detailed comment below

Comment: I recommend watching/reading some tutorials such as [Laravel from Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch). Whilst this might seem "boring", they will provide you with the fundamental building blocks to progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read through the basics section on the docs, good ones that you'd need to use initially to get started are:

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade

In the simplest way possible, you'll define in your routes a url path that you want to define, and then pass in the controller and method it is refering to. You can put in some basic 'business logic' (basically server logic on data) in there.

Then the controller will return a view, with `view('some.blade.file')` possible with some data using `->with('data', $data)` if you want.

Then in your view you will have your html, which is actually blade syntax, which under the hood gets complied to php, and then that gets complied to the raw html your browser sees when hitting that route.

You can stitch together blade files so they extend off other blade files, and you can have a blade file that adds in the auth nav bar if that's what you want.

Comment: (edit: I see you've deleted your comment now!) to be honest it's hard to find those exactly because the command you've used to generate the ui is depreciated and is now the old way of doing it. It still works but there's limited resources on it https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication (<- see only 7.x laravel).

The Views provided by this should still be published to the resources/views/auth folder I believe